# Как после каждого символа ставить точку?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
data = 'ghbdtn'
```

Как после каждого символа ставить точку(любой знак)?! Или есть другой способ 
  как из каждого символа получить такой результат?

```
print(data.split('.'))
```

Чтобы в конце получилось что-то вроде этого =>

```
['g', 'h', 'b', 'd', 't', 'n', '']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы получить такой результат как в вопросе:

```
print(list(data))
```